# How to add an element and sort an array whiling iterating?

Tags: java

Could you one help please to resolve this problem?
I have an ArrayList of nodes that is sorted by ascending order based on ratio of distance. Then I started to assign them to depots one by one, starting from the first customer on the ArrayList with the minimum ratio. Also the capacity of depots are considered during the process of assigning nodes. Moreover, it is not allowed to violate capacity of the depot. Notice that the total demand of all nodes are less than or  equal to the capacity.

During the process of assignment, if there is a node cannot assigned to the depot, then it is required to recalculate its ratio at the same time starting from the second nearest depot to the third nearest depot. Finally, the new ratio is inserted into the ArrayList and sort it again, and so completed the assignment process.

So, the ArrayList, while iterating, I would like to add a new element and sort it?
Here is the code.
Many Thanks,

**Main Class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Depot> depots = new ArrayList<Depot>();
        Depot A = new Depot(1, 80);         
                depots.add(A);
        Depot B = new Depot(2, 100);        
                depots.add(B);
        Depot C = new Depot(3, 160);        
                depots.add(C);

        ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Node n1 = new Node(1, 17, A, 9, B, 20, C, 30);
        nodes.add(n1);
        Node n2 = new Node(2, 18, A, 17, C, 23, B, 30);
        nodes.add(n2);
        Node n3 = new Node(3, 13, A, 10, B, 21, C, 42);
        nodes.add(n3);
        Node n4 = new Node(4, 19, A, 5, B, 24, C, 33);
        nodes.add(n4);      
        Node n5 = new Node(5, 12, A, 3, B, 30, C, 41); 
        nodes.add(n5);
        Node n6 = new Node(6, 18, B, 6, A, 23, C, 30);
        nodes.add(n6);
        Node n7 = new Node(7, 13, A, 19, B, 27, C, 53);
        nodes.add(n7);
        Node n8 = new Node(8, 13, B, 4, A, 26, C, 30);
        nodes.add(n8);
        Node n9 = new Node(9, 17, C, 19, A, 24, B, 19);
        nodes.add(n9);
        Node n10 = new Node(10, 20, C, 5, A, 36, B, 36);
        nodes.add(n10);
        Node n11 = new Node(11, 16, B, 11, C, 24, A, 25);
        nodes.add(n11);
        Node n12 = new Node(12, 18, A, 11, B, 19, C, 29);
        nodes.add(n12);
        Node n13 = new Node(13, 15, A, 4, B, 31, C, 39);
        nodes.add(n13);
        Node n14 = new Node(14, 11, B, 17, A, 18, C, 23);
        nodes.add(n14);
        Node n15 = new Node(15, 18, C, 16, B, 20, A, 25);
        nodes.add(n15);
        Node n16 = new Node(16, 16, C, 10, B, 24, A, 32);
        nodes.add(n16);
        Node n17 = new Node(17, 15, A, 19, C, 22, B, 32);
        nodes.add(n17);
        Node n18 = new Node(18, 15, A, 7, B, 29, C, 32);
        nodes.add(n18);
        Node n19 = new Node(19, 15, B, 18, C, 33, A, 43);
        nodes.add(n19);
        Node n20 = new Node(20, 16, A, 10, C, 32, B, 33);
        nodes.add(n20);

        realtive(depots, nodes);
        for(Depot d : depots) {
            System.out.println("Depot No. : " + d.getId());
            for(Node n : d.getNodeList()) {
                System.out.print(n.getId() + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void realtive(ArrayList<Depot> depots, ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
        ArrayList<Node> newList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for(Node n : nodes) {
            if(n.getIsAssigned() == false && n.getDegree() == 1) {              
                double ratio = (double) n.getDistance_1() / n.getDistance_2();              
                n.setRatio(ratio);
                newList.add(n);
            }
            if(n.getIsAssigned() == false && n.getDegree() == 2) {
                double ratio = (double) n.getDistance_2() / n.getDistance_3();
                n.setRatio(ratio);
                newList.add(n);
            }
            if(n.getIsAssigned() == false && n.getDegree() == 3) {
                double ratio = (double) n.getDistance_3() / n.getDistance_3();
                n.setRatio(ratio);
                newList.add(n);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(newList);

        boolean isAssigned = false;
        for(Node n : newList) {
            for(Depot d : depots) {
                isAssigned = assignNode(n, d, n.getDegree());
            }
            if(isAssigned = false)
                break;
        }

        int count = 0;
        for(Node n : nodes) {
            if(n.getIsAssigned() == false) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        if(count < nodes.size()){
            realtive(depots, nodes);
        }
    }

    public static boolean assignNode(Node n, Depot d, int i) {
        boolean isAssigned = false;
        if(n.getDegree() == 1) {
            if(n.getIsAssigned() == false && n.getDepot_1().equals(d) && n.getDemand() <= d.getCapacity()) {
            d.addNode(n);
            n.setIsAssigned(true);
            isAssigned = true;
            } else {
                n.increaseDegree();
                isAssigned = false;
            }
        }
        if(n.getDegree() == 2) {
            if(n.getIsAssigned() == false && n.getDepot_2().equals(d) && n.getDemand() <= d.getCapacity()) {
            d.addNode(n);
            n.setIsAssigned(true);
            isAssigned = true;
            } else {
                n.increaseDegree();
                isAssigned = false;
            }
        }
        if(n.getDegree() == 3) {
            if(n.getIsAssigned() == false && n.getDepot_3().equals(d) && n.getDemand() <= d.getCapacity()) {
            d.addNode(n);
            n.setIsAssigned(true);
            isAssigned = true;
            } else {
                n.increaseDegree();
                isAssigned = false;
            }
        }
        return isAssigned;
    }
```

**Depot Class:**

```
public Depot(int myId, int myCapacity) {
    id = myId;
    capacity = myCapacity;
    nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
}

public void addNode(Node n) {
    nodeList.add(n);
    capacity -= n.getDemand();
}

public int getId() { return id; }
public int getCapacity() { return capacity; }
public List<Node> getNodeList() { return nodeList; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the question correctly. Where is the part where you are *iterating the list*?

Comment: if(count < nodes.size()){
            realtive(depots, nodes);
        }

Comment: This code will assign each Node to the nearest Depot, when the capacity of the Depot cannot take more Nodes, I need to calculate the ration again but this time between the 2nd depot and the 3ed depot. this ratio, should be add to the arrayList and sort it before starting assigned again.

Comment: The question is highly unclear. You should include more details of the problem that you are facing. Expected and observed behaviour of the code and error stack if any.

Comment: Change: if(isAssigned = false) break; TO: if(isAssigned == false) { break; } or better yet: if(!isAssigned) { break; }. You had forgot an equals character within your condition, an easy mistake for anyone. What your line is doing is assigning false to the **isAssigned** boolean variable within the **if** condition. See if this helps you.

Comment: Does the order of elements in the list matter?

Comment: Yes it is. The elements on the arraylist was sorted based on ratio.